# How to pass absolute path as an argument in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am a beginner in shell scripting. I am trying to change directory in a shell script by passing an absolute path as an argument. I am trying to do it with `cd` command but it's not working.  Any idea how to specify an absolute path? e.g, currently I'm in `/home/malik1` and I want to  go to  `/home/documents`

What I've done:

```
if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then

    cd $1
```

Correct me please if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: How do you notice it is not working? Could you provide the complete script? You are aware of the fact that a script can only change its working directory, but not of its caller?

Comment: I assume your directory does not happen to have a space in its name, otherwise you'd see an error message upon executing your script. What I mean is that you should quote the variable in the invocation of `cd`, that is, use `cd "$1"`. This prevents errors with variables containing spaces, newline, or other special characters.

Comment: Isn't the correct path `/home/malik1/documents`?